# preg_replace pattern for inches replacement PHP with word boundry

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace something like:

```
Remo Suede Emperor Drumhead 12" or
Remo Suede Emperor 12" Drumhead
```

on

```
Remo Suede Emperor Drumhead 12inch or
Remo Suede Emperor 12inch Drumhead
```

Do you know what pattern would be best for `preg_replace` function ?

P.S. would be good to have a word boundry in there too to avoid false positivies replacamenet ie.

```
123M90"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/([0-9])"/', '$1inch', $string);
```

Comment: any ideas how to include word boundry in it ?

Comment: Try this: `preg_replace('/([0-9])"(\W)/', '$1inch$2', $string);` Notice how $1 and $2 contains the same value as the content in the first and second parenthesis.

Comment: nope, doesn't work, I were thinking something like `/\b([0-9])"/` (as its about boundry at front) but also not working

Comment: seems like `/\b([0-9]+)"/` and `/\b([0-9]*)"/` both works, what is the difference ?

Comment: `/\b([0-9]+)"/` requires that there is at least one digit between the word boundary and the `"`, whereas `/\b([0-9]*)"/` also accepts zero digits. So the first does not match a space followed by `"` and the second does.

Comment: none of them does i.e. `new 15 " TV` won't be replaced by any of those patterns

Comment: btw, I have moved that question under: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166996/php-preg-replace-pattern-differences-and I will close that, thanks

Comment: Marcin, why didn't you show these new forms of replacement in your question? `preg_replace('/\b([0-9]+)\h*"(\W)/', '$1inch$2', $string);` or similar may fit your needs. This will remove horizontal whitespace between the number and the `"`. If you want to save the whitespace, move `\h*` inside the first parenthesis or maybe just add a space after `$1`