# Regex Pattern Differences - "*" and "+"

Tags: php, regex, repeat

I am trying to replace `"` on `inch` i.e. `12" wall` would become `12 inch wall`

I have 2 patterns working:

```
/\b([0-9]+)"/ -> preg_replace('/\b([0-9]+)"/', '$1 inch ', $string)
```

and

```
/\b([0-9]*)"/ -> preg_replace('/\b([0-9]*)"/', '$1 inch ', $string)
```

what is a difference between them then, why `+` and `*` works same way here  ?

cheers,
/Marcin

Comment: Do you know what `*` and `+` mean?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The + means find the previous character/group 1 or more times.

The * means find the previous character/group any amount of times (0-infinity)

Comment: in the example above they seem to perform exactly same function and can't find differences

Comment: they will behave the same if there is either no number, or a number (both will match the number and quote if there is one, or will return no matches if nothing is before the quote). However the one with the * will match the quote if it is preceded by a letter/word, whereas the one with the + will not.
`([0-9]*)\"` matches `"` in `new brown" wall` - but
`([0-9]+)\"` matches nothing in `new brown" wall`

Comment: If `12"` is the only possible match in your test case, then indeed both perform the same.

Comment: great, thanks SmokeyPHP, nice one, and thanks Arjan for your hep too.

Answer (score 1):

`/\b([0-9]+)"/` requires that there is at least one digit between the word boundary and the `"`, whereas `/\b([0-9]*)"/` also accepts zero digits. So the first does not match a space followed by `"` and the second does.

If you want to mach both `new 15 " tv` and `new 15" tv` you need to match against a space character that may or may not be present:

```
/\b([0-9]+)\s?"/
```

This matches a word boundary, followed by a sequence (on or more) numbers, optionally followed by one space (or tab), followed by a `"`. I presume that's what you are looking for.
If not, you should first define strings that must match and strings that may not match.

Comment: none of them does i.e. `new 15 " TV` won't be replaced by any of those patterns

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted `\b`, but if you want to match both `new 15 " TV` and `new 15" TV` you do not need word boundaries. I'll update my answer.

Comment: `15 "` won't be matched because you aren't allowing spaces, I would suggest `([0-9]+)\s?\"` - note the `\s?`, this means an optional space

Comment: Yeah, I need to have a word boundary at front to avoid `"MPN16754"`

Comment: The thing is that those patters works great I only want to match `new 15" TV` but would like to understand why there is no differences between those 2 patterns and if its normal which one to use `+` or `*`